# struts2 image button cannot calculate source of image

Tags: struts2

I need embed image button to page under Struts2.
Unfortunately absolute path cannot be used, so I need application-related url, but `<s:submit type="image" src="i/go_btn.gif"` doesn't work and expected url: `app/i/go_btn.gif` is not resolved. On other hand `<s:url` cannot be used because of error: "src does not accept any expressions"

So question: how to specify url of image in s:submit tag in application relative format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my own solution. It is appeared that template for submit control (submit.ftl) contains following line for **src** attribute:

```
<#if parameters.src??>
  src="${parameters.src?html}"<#rt/>
</#if>
```

That is why code for `<input type="image"` always generated with specified URL. It have to be changed as follow:

```
<#if parameters.src??>
   src='<@s.url value="${parameters.src?html}" includeParams="none" />'<#rt/>
</#if>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a root relative path perhaps.

placing "/" before the url means the root of the app. See http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/RelativeLinks

Comment: not at all, this doesn't work. This was first thing I ever tried to deal with this problem. It renders as is: `<input type="image" name="method:onSend" id="question_title_cabinet_send" src="/i/go_btn.gif" alt="Go">` But have to be: '/app/i/go_btn.gif'